In PaintWeight, Is it possible to select multiple bones while Vertex Selection Mode is ON?
I do not intend to use Mask Modifier because I have a hair mesh that contains 5-10 layers on top of each other and I would rather work with two mesh surfaces that are stacked visibly in edit/Weight paint mode and hide the rest so I can see better where it deforms when I posed it.
I selected the group from the underneath of the surface mesh that I want to mask and paint weight over however I noticed that I could not select different bones once I turned on the Vertex Selection Mode.
OFC I can go through different vextex group but I find it very tedious to scroll through every time especially when it is a long list.
It would be easier if there is such feature that allow user to  shift different bones while the  vertex selection masking is active under Paint Weight.
If it is not possible, what is the hotkey for vertex selection ??

Anyone??  I'm asking if it's possible to work both ways with vertex selection mode On while selecting different bones in Weight Paint

I don't know about painting with multiple bones selected-- I have no idea what that would do, but I imagine it must do something or you wouldn't bring it up.  If I want to switch between groups in vertex masking (and I always use vertex masking), I would select the vertex group from the sidebar.

@ Nathan  Yes I know  but what I'm asking is if there is easier method to select bone  so I don't have to go through a long list of my vertex group and select there.

Not from the properties window-- from the sidebar.  There should only be a few weights on any particular vertex.  (And if there are a bunch of zero weights, it's time to run a clean operation anyways.)

Can you point out where I'm supposed to look in the sidebar?

Example pic at https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/1/b/9/1b9c279bb0f986045cb04af3f5ae0cb9f896c415.jpeg from https://blenderartists.org/t/rigging-issues-vertex-groups-not-applying-to-rig/1365959/5

Oh I see. The problem with this is that I'm working on a complicated hair mesh with multiple layers that are stacking on top of each other.   I created a vertex group for a top layer as a selection for masking which essentially the vertex weight in the side bar will not show up unless I go back to the edit mode and select a certain portion amount of the vertices that are affected which quite frankly it is annoying.

When weight painting, personally, I frequently tab to edit to get different selections (that's kinda why I always use vertex masking.)  I'm not sure I'm getting your exact situation.  But you might just find it useful to learn about vertex group filtering, which means you don't have to search through a million groups: click on the field beneath your vertex group list, in the properties field, and type something in.  Like, "hair.001".  Or, ".r".
